# Impersonation for connect to remote machine in windows application(c#)

Tags: c#, passwords, impersonation

I writing a code which connects to server(WINDOWS NT 200) and performance some action.I am not having rights for performing operation.so,I am using IMPERSONATION but getting error as "UNKNOWN USER NAME AND BAD PASSWORD". User name and password are correct one.

Same code i used in following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that impersonation does not give you rights & permissions to do some actions, it only gives you the possibility to impersonate a different user than the current one and to do actions "as you were" that user. If the user you are impersonating has not permissions to do something, you will not be able to act with elevated privileges.

That said, you will find lot of similar scenarios on SO that maybe already covers your situation.
To start, try take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189565/logon-failure-unknown-user-name-or-bad-password-error-while-accessing-other-ser) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563724/accessing-password-protected-network-drives-in-windows-in-c) - hope that helps.

Comment: I asked this question because .......my application connects to IBM MQ manager(on server: windows 2000 NT) and puts the message on the queue.I am able to connect to MQ manager but when i try to put message on the queue i getting authorization error.                                             So,I am trying to use IMPERSONATION to put message on the queue .....will this be possible to do?

Comment: I honestly don't know much about IBM MQ - anyway, with impersonation you can act as different user than the local one. That is, if in your server you have a user with full access/privileges to IBM MQ manager and you know its password, you can impersonate that user and gain its full privileges. If you have the possibility, try to run your application locally inside the server, logged as the user you want to impersonate, and check if you have the same error message (to better understand if the problem came from the low-level privileges of the user or the client-server connection)

Comment: I have details like remote machine's(windows 2000 NT,were IBM MQ installed) IP address,domain[CORP or TXUCORP],username ,password.....i used a code in above link .it is not working for me. My application will runs on  windwos 7 as client app .It needs connect to remote machine at runtime using impersonation method .               MSDN says we can impersonate user on local user only, not on remote machine.                                                                          Can we be able to this? I am waiting for your comments @Spaceman