# How to create Folder on remote computer with passward

Tags: vb.net

I got `Access denied` error while creating a folder on remote computer

```
Dim findDirectory = "\\SERVER\D$\AAA"
Dim Y_N = System.IO.Directory.Exists(findDirectory)
If Y_N = True Then
Else
    Directory.CreateDirectory(findDirectory)
End If
Dim MyFilename = findDirectory & "\" & Today.Day & "-" & 
    Today.Month & "-" & Today.Year & "-" & tineNow & "-" & Today.Minute & ".wav"
FileCopy("\\SERVER\D$\AAA\test.wav", MyFilename1)
```

Comment: You most likely do not have the permission to create the folder.

Comment: how to get permission of remote computer ?

Comment: First, check whether you can manually create a folder in `findDirectory`. If you can, then your program should also be able to.

Comment: To change folder permission see [this](https://www.google.ca/search?source=hp&ei=ie8yXfqzGY7b5gK766r4CQ&q=windows+set+folder+permission&oq=windows+set+folder+permission&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19l2j0i22i30i19l8.2050.7719..10054...0.0..0.124.2790.17j13......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0j0i131j0i13i30i19j0i22i30.pbvhDK015hk&ved=0ahUKEwi6nKq8p8PjAhWOrVkKHbu1Cp8Q4dUDCAg&uact=5).

Comment: Or you have a double-hop problem (if your application runs under impersonated credentials or the like then you can't (easily) create a folder on an SMB share as it then would be the 3rd hop - you might try impersonation with delegate rights then but no warranties that it is gonna work).

Comment: thanks All , i find solution from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189565/logon-failure-unknown-user-name-or-bad-password-error-while-accessing-other-ser

Comment: ' i firstly created this function                                                                                               
Public Shared Function LogonUser(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, _
    ByVal lpszPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
    ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Comment: 'then i used this function as                                                                                     Dim admin_token As IntPtr
Dim wid_current As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
Dim wid_admin As WindowsIdentity = Nothing
Dim wic As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing 
If LogonUser("Server", "ComputerName", "Passward", 9, 0, admin_token) <> 0 Then 
wid_admin = New WindowsIdentity(admin_token)
wic = wid_admin.Impersonate()
' copyfile code
End If